# Point mobile scanner with cordova not working

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I am developing application in cordova, using plugin for scanning with point mobile.

**Device android version: 5.0.2**

**My cordova version is 7.1.0,**

**Android platform is 5.2.0 :**

I have added point mobile plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-pm80-scanner

**Problem is when I try to use it I got this error in cordova.js . It used to work before we updated our device. I don't think this is problem with wrong callbacks. I noticed that the property bellow, utils.typeName(args[i]) is Number, not ArrayBuffer. I don't know if it is correct.**

[image]

**I am having this method in my js file.**

```
function pointMobileScan(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.plugins.pm80scanner.setTriggerMode(cordova.plugins.pm80scanner.TRIGGER_MODE.ONESHOT);
    cordova.plugins.pm80scanner.set(
        function (result) {
            successCallback(result);
        },
        function (error) {
            errorCallback(error);
        }
    );
}
```

I also tried to change the plugin's device.sdk to newest 5.0.2(http://www.pointmobile.co.kr/download_list_new.php?sca=SDK&model=), but it's not the cause of problem I think. Maybe inside the plugin could be error?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Looks like `args` doesn't exist.  Please read [ask] - this question is well below required standards for a valid question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Archer looks like you don't know cordova. Otherwise you would understand the question...

Comment: Sure - that's right.  I suggest you fix your question (and your attitude) if you want any help.  Good luck ;)

Comment: @Archer sorry for me being rude. I just saw you downvote and suggest the most wise think I woulnd come up with, that args does't exists :P

Comment: I downvoted because your question has no code in it, which is explained in the link I gave you - [ask].  Without code to reproduce your issue this isn't a valid question and is of no use to the SO community.  Sorry if that seems harsh, but it's just a fact - nothing personal.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and sorry once again. I have changed at least one of the pictures to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with 
- upgrade cordova 8.0.0
- upgrade android-platform 6.4.0
- upgrade plugins